# How can I summarize this formula in excel?

Tags: excel

I want to calculate the sum of the digits of a number that is **at least five digits**. I want to use a formula like this(for a 5 digits number):

MOD(INT(A1),10)+MOD(INT(A1/10),10)+MOD(INT(A1/100),10)+MOD(INT(A1/1000),10)+MOD(INT(A1/10000),10)

but it becomes too long for a ten digits number(for example).
is there any approach to summarize this formula? FOR loop or any other thing.

**I don't want to use MACROS or VBA** and just want to type it in formula box.

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**With Excel 365**

with a 5-digit number in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=SUM(--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(5),1))
```

[image]

*(no vba, no macros)*

For an integer of arbitrary size, you could use:

```
=SUM(--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))
```

[image]

or:

```
=IF(A1="",0,SUM(--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))
```

**EDIT#1:**

**Without Excel 365**

Use this *Array formula*:

```
=SUM(--MID($A$1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

[image]

Comment: excuse me, I'm beginner in excel, what is excel365? I am using excel 2016 and when I type your suggestion in formula box , it shows #NAME? in B1 cell. how can I fix it? thanks

Comment: @abcdef  Then ignore my answer.

Comment: @abcdef  See my **EDIT#1** for a formula that should work for your version of Excel.

Comment: @abcdef  In the future, I will attempt to offer both *Excel 365* and *pre-Excel 365* formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Place your number in `A1` and stretch this over the necessary number of cells (i.e. the number of digits) in the second row, starting with `A2`, to place each digit in it's own cell.

```
=MOD(INT($A$1/POWER(10,COLUMN(A2)-1)),10)
```

and then add a `SUM` function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.

we should type this formula:

=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(INT(A1/{1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000}),10))